# Use jQuery in Fluid.app's Userscripts?

Tags: macos, open-source, javascript, fluid.app

In [Fluid.app](https://fluidapp.com)'s Userscripts section, you can write custom Javascript to modify the embedded site. Cool! My Fluid app's embedded site has the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library loaded. I'd like to reference and use that jQuery library  from within my Userscripts… but it seems that it's not available to the Userscript.

How can I reference the already loaded jQuery library from within my Userscripts?

Comment: Have you considered just including jquery in the code of your userscript? (Copy and paste the mini'd library) Messy, but lacking a better solution, there's no reason it shouldn't work.